# Remove HTML by div id inside C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

See below code, I want to remove particular content in between from full html source code.

do anyone has suggestion?

```
var hmtl = '<DIV><div>This is test things.</div><div id='test'><div class='ourteam_link'> < ul class='ourteam_menu_left'> <li class='active'><a href = '#' > All Candidates</a></li> <li><a href = '#' > Favorites </ a ></ li > < li >< a href='#'>Hidden</a></li>  </ul><span>Sort by: <a href = '#' > Rank </ a ></ span > </ div ></div><div>Footer remain</div></DIV>';

int a = hmtl.IndexOf("<div id='test'>");
int b = hmtl.LastIndexOf("<div id='test'>"); 
hmtl = hmtl.Remove(a, (b - a));
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the <div id='test'> element as well? You have to include the length of the pattern in the b index.

Comment: what do you want to remove exactly?

Comment: That's fine, it can help both even if we remove that ''<div id='test'>'' or we keep it. but i want to remove content inside it and replace with my specific variable.

Comment: What if you have only one occurrence? In your example that tag appears only once. In that case what action you want to take? Secondly, please edit your question to clarify input and output. You mentioned remove in your question and now you are telling replace with another value. These are different.

Comment: I don't know what parts you want to remove, but I suggest using regex.

Comment: you can tell me only for remove html inside that div. rest i will manage

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to do that.

```
<div>
  <div>This is test things.</div>
  <div id='test'>
    <div class='ourteam_link'>
      <ul class='ourteam_menu_left'>
        <li class='active'>
          <a href='#'>All Candidates</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Favorites </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Hidden</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span>Sort by: <a href='#'>Rank </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>Footer remain</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
//Calling function
myFunction();

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("test");
  x.innerHTML = '<div>New</div>';
}
</script>
```